# Class cast Exception in Android string.xml

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am developing an Android-App that uses the Facebook-SDKv3, so I created an entry in the strings.xml:

```
<resources>
  <string name="facebook_app_id">"12345678910"</string>
</resources>
```

and added the following to the Manifest:

```
<application>
  ...
  <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:resource="@string/facebook_app_id" />
</application>
```

I always get this Exception:

> 02-06 16:35:01.231: W/Bundle(8316): Key com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value  was returned.
>   
> 02-06 16:35:01.231: W/Bundle(8316): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
>   
> 02-06 16:35:01.231: W/Bundle(8316): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>   
> 02-06 16:35:01.231: W/Bundle(8316): at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1061)
>   
> 02-06 16:35:01.231: W/Bundle(8316): at com.facebook.internal.Utility.getMetadataApplicationId(Utility.java:159)

I already tried to put the Numbers in "" but this did not solve the Problem, hope somebody can help me.

Comment: but right format is `<string name="facebook_app_id">12345678910</string>`

Comment: yes I know and already tried it, but someone suggest to put it in "".

Comment: Shouldn't it be `android:value` instead of `android:resource` ?

Comment: i don't known why someone suggest u you can see [this](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeyAndroid/blob/master/res/values/strings.xml) example

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change it from `android:resource` to `android:value`

Comment: Silly developer documents!